# This number is not natural

Tags: elementary-number-theory, harmonic-numbers

Let $k$ be a natural number, such that $k>1$.

Show that $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{k}$ is not a natural number.

How I can prove this?

Comment: Have you looked up on the web ?

Comment: this question has been asked a many many times before

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Consider the highest power of $2$ that divides $k$, and the highest power of $2$ lesser than $k$.
- Bertrand's postulate leads to a shorter solution. This result is highly non-trivial, though, and it is often not allowed in introductory courses of number theory.